# MOS amplifiers CMRR question

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, differential

As we know ,in MOS differential amplifiers we have Rd mismatch and gm mismatch.These mismatches have effects on the differential amplifier.Which of the effects of these mismatches is more dominant in your opinion ?And why

Comment: You forgot a big one anf in my opinion the main contributor to mismatch ! The threshold voltage Vt !

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a big one and in my opinion the main contributor to mismatch ! The threshold voltage Vt !

gm is directly related to Vgt (Vgt = Vgs -Vt) so here you see that a mismatch in Vt also gives a mismatch in Vgt and therefore gm.

Rd is quite unpredictable so it's best to load the differential pair with a low-ohmic load like a mirror input diode or a cascode. That way, Rd doesn't matter much.

But depending on the design and how the transistors are biased things can be completely different ! You cannot say X is always more dominant than Y, because it depends on many other factors !